# What is tick value in arangoDB WAL?

Tags: arangodb

I am trying to understand the HTTP API provided by the arangoDB to access WAL. In this i found this tick value that is included in WAL. What is this tick value and what it does?

Thank you

Comment: Vote to close, as this is not programming problem the community can solve for you.  A `tick` in the sense used in the API is an atomically increasing "time marker" (wikipedia: `Tick, atomic unit used to define system time in computing`, and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_time#Implementation)